# How to render a new state on the click of a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So I've been learning react but I'm having some trouble with forms.

I'm able to change a state after clicking a button in a form. However I've only been able to find resources that show me how to alert the new state.

What if I want to render the new state into the DOM?

I don't necessarily need the answer but would love to be shown the resources to figure out the answer myself to help me learn.

Here's what I've got:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { username: '',};
  }

  myChangeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState ({username: e.target.value});
  }

  mySubmitHandler = () => {
    alert(this.state.username);
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <form>
              <p>Enter your name, and submit:</p>

              <input
                  type='text'
                  onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
              />

              <button onClick={this.mySubmitHandler}>Submit</button>

          </form>

      );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyForm />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: did you try `this.setState({...this.state})`?

Comment: `render` is called automatically on component's state or props change. So only add `{this.state.username}` inside the rendered JSX and it should show the up to date value.

Answer (score 0):

Make a state for display as the part of component state.

```js
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = { userNameForInput: '', userNameForDisplay: ''}; // add 'userNameForDisplay'
  }

  myChangeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState ({ userNameForInput: e.target.value });
  }

  mySubmitHandler = () => {
    this.setState ({ userNameForDisplay: this.state.userNameForInput });  // update `userNameForDisplay` by 'userNameForInput'
  }

  render() {
      const { userNameForInput, userNameForDisplay } = this.state

      return (
          <form>
              <p>Enter your name, and submit:</p>

              <input
                  type='text'
                  onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
              />

              <button onClick={this.mySubmitHandler}>Submit</button>

               {/* render 'userNameForInput', 'userNameForDisplay' to DOM */}
               {/* the format to render js variable in jsx is '{ jsVariable }' */}
               <div>UserName From Input(update by input change): { userNameForInput }<div>
               <div>UserName For Submit(update by submit button): { userNameForDisplay }<div>
          </form>

      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly!

And your explanation really helps to understand.